# How to set application path as actuator base path (@ApplicationPath)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-boot-actuator, actuator

I have enabled actuator for a spring boot application and I'm able to access it using http://localhost:8080/actuator/ --- **This is working!**

But I'm trying allow access using application path; For example: http://localhost:8080/my-app/actuator/

Changing the following doesn't help either.

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path = my-app
```

Accessing this URL http://localhost:8080/my-app/actuator/ --gives 404

As I'm deploying this particular application in Docker swarm behind a Spring gateway, i should allow this access.

Comment: I think the configuration should be `management.endpoints.web.base-path=/my-app/actuator` if you want that URL to work.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek Nope. It doesn't work that way neither. Still gives 404.

Comment: I don't get it : your application is not exposed to `/` but behind `/my-app` ? What property are you using for this ?

Comment: @LaurentSchoelens we have defined it using @ApplicationPath("/my-app")

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should be trying to use the
[`server.servlet.context-path`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#application-properties.server.server.servlet.context-path) property and setting it to `/my-app` and then remove your `@ApplicationPath("/my-app")`

As suggested in the documentation of [`management.endpoints.web.base-path`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#application-properties.actuator.management.endpoints.web.base-path) property :

> Base path for Web endpoints. Relative to the servlet context path (`server.servlet.context-path`) or WebFlux base path (`spring.webflux.base-path`) when the management server is sharing the main server port. Relative to the management server base path (`management.server.base-path`) when a separate management server port (`management.server.port`) is configured.

Comment: Well, this will work only when adding a separate management.server.port. Now it will work as http://localhost:8585/my-app/actuator/ with a different port. I'm trying to achieve with same port.

Comment: What did you change ? Adding the `management.server.port` ?

Comment: My answer was removing the `management.endpoints.web.base-path` and setting `server.servlet.context-path` from which the actuator endpoint is relative from.

Comment: Added management.server.servlet.context-path = /my-app . When adding a separate context-path for management server, it it mandatory to run the management server on a different port

Comment: Thanks. Could you try the `server.servlet.context-path` approach ? With removing `@ApplicationPath("/my-app")`

Comment: I have tried this approach. But in this way  I'm not able to access neither my APIs nor actuator endpoints.